# enable_if function defined when it shouldn't be

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

As an experiment, I am trying to make a void member function with no parameters change behavior based on the class template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
  void MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T> dummy = T());
  void MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T> dummy = T());

};

template<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T> dummy)
{
}

template<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T> dummy)
{
}

class Simple {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  MyClass<int> myClass;
  myClass.MyFunc();

//   MyClass<Simple> myClass2;
//   myClass2.MyFunc();

  return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting: error: call of overloaded ‘MyFunc()’ is ambiguous. Shouldn't only one or the other of those functions get defined, since everything is the same except for a ! in one of them?

Comment: downvoting ... you should avoid changing your question to include the fix we tell you. it will confuse everyone. please undo that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make dummy template parameters to do what I was asking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
  template <typename U = T>
  void MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<U>::value, U>::type dummy = U());
  template <typename U = T>
  void MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value, U>::type dummy = U());
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<U>::value, U>::type dummy)
{
}

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void MyClass<T>::MyFunc(const typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value, U>::type dummy)
{
}

class Simple {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  MyClass<int> myClass;
  myClass.MyFunc();

  MyClass<Simple> myClass2;
  myClass2.MyFunc();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, first you need to actually access the `::type` typedef of `enable_if`, and second, your code will not work because your members are not templates. One of them always will end up being an invalid declaration.

After applying the necessary `::type` fix, your code will fail when instantiating `MyClass<int>`, long before you try to call the member.

Make your members member templates, and make the `enable_if` depend on a parameter of the member template, instead of on a parameter of the enclosing class template.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way to do this? Have a non-templated member function change behavior based on the template parameter of the class?

Comment: @DavidDoria call an overload. `return MyFuncImpl(std::is_fundamental<T>());`. Overload that on `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Say:

```
std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T>::type
//                                              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I tried that first (now edited into the original post) but I get error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, int>’

Comment: @DavidDoria: Correct. When the bool is false, there is *no* type. This is the error that Isn't An Error in SFINAE.

Comment: Actually that is an error because there is no template substitution in a non-template.

Comment: @visitor: Indeed, the OP still has to integrate this building block into a proper SFINAE construction. I just meant to point out where the substitution failure will occur.